# Getting service reference from Azure WorkerRole

Tags: wcf, iis, azure, azure-worker-roles, service-reference

I want my WorkerRole application to be able to interface. I've written the WCF interface/proxy and I want to now be able to consume it from the client application. I've tried hosting the worker role on my local machine, tracing the endpoint IP address and then in my client solution, tried adding a service reference to the IP address, however VS2012 cannot find it ((interestingly it's not using the same port i specified, rather the next one above it). I then tried publishing my worker role to Azure, and then grabbing the IP from there and connection. Still it cannot find the service reference. I started IIS on both my machine and the azure instance... but it still didn't work.

Anyway, I tried using svcutil and I got

> ```
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://127.255.0. 2:9192/Test'.
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Fault xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/
> ```
>
> 05/soap-envelope">`Sendera:ActionNotSupported`
>
> > The message with Action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2 004/09/transfer/Get' cannot be
> >     processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilte r mismatch at the
> >     EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract m ismatch
> >     (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security
> >     m ismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and
> >     receiver hav e the same contract and the same binding (including
> >     security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport,
> >     None).

Anyway, I tried just manually connecting a clien the the host with the IP address. My client makes a connection to the host as it invokes a procedure called search. I can break point on the host when I make the call from the client. Unfortunately, the host is meant to return a string, yet the client only receives a null. What is going on? Below is my code:

Client:

```
private string serviceURL = "net.tcp://127.255.0.2:9192/Test";



private ITest GetAProxy()
{
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
    var endpointAddress
        = new EndpointAddress(serviceURL);

    return new ChannelFactory<ITest>
        (binding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
}


[DataContract]
public class Send
{
    [DataMember]
    public String s { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class Recieve
{
    [DataMember]
    public String x { get; set; }
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    Send Search(Recieve rec);
}
```

Host:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class TestClass : ITest
{

    public Send Search(Recieve rec)
    {


        var s = new Send(); //I can breakpoint here
        s.s = "This will be received as a null";

        return s;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Send
{
    [DataMember]
    public String s { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class Recieve
{
    [DataMember]
    public String x { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    Send Search(Recieve rec);
}
```

edit: Also if I set property x in Receive when I make call to the Search() method, the server receives null.

Comment: Have you specified the service endpoint in the azure service configuration file?  BTW - you will never be able to reference an Azure worker role by IP address - they are always hosted behind a load balancer.

Comment: I know you're specifically asking for help with a worker role.  If you want to consider a Web Role instead, I have a detailed blog on this topic.  At the very least, perhaps you'll find something in my solution that you're overlooking.
http://rickrainey.com/2013/08/30/hosting-a-wcf-service-in-an-azure-web-role-with-http-tcp-endpoints/

Comment: I got it working when hosting in my local emulator, but yes, how do I connect to an instance which is behind an azure load balancer?

Comment: also, people seem to have it working in azure here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188464/Host-WCF-Services-in-an-Azure-Worker-Role